# How do I make changes in a particular React component from a Flask server?

Tags: python, ajax, reactjs, flask

I hope my question is clear enough.

So, I have a React form in component A. I want to pass the fields using an AJAX request to a Flask server, which processes the data received and updates the DOM in component B.

Tried looking up several other SO pages but none of them answered the question. And I'm super new to both AJAX and Flask, so that doesn't help either.

My current code looks like this:

Component A:

```
import React from "react";

class InputForm extends React.Component {
  claimRef = React.createRef();
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const claim = this.claimRef.current.value;
    this.props.addClaim(claim);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/test/",
      data: claim
    })
      .done(function(data) {
        // self.clearForm();
      })
      .fail(function(jqXhr) {
        console.log("failed to register");
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Claim:
          <textarea name="claim" ref={this.claimRef} placeholder="Claim" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default InputForm;
```

Flask server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/test/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    clicked = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        clicked = request
    return render_template('test.html', clicked=clicked)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=os.environ.get('PORT', 3000), debug=True)
```

I've added a `test.html` file temporarily, which is supposed to simply print the data, but even localhost:3000/test just prints "None".

I get absolutely no errors in any part of the application, and I also get `status 200` in the network tab of the webpage, which means that the data is being accepted.

How do I access the passed data and subsequently, print it in component B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your reactjs http post, however I would recommend you to use the fetch api. However, when you want to talk to the client from your server you have to use json.

Here is how you would make an http request to the server try this:

```js
const data = this.claimRef.current.value;
fetch('/test/', {
        method: "POST", 
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Once you create make the http post to the server, this is how you retrieve the data from the server (flask)

```py
@app.route('/test/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    clicked = None
    if request.method == "POST":
     data = request.json
     print(data) #json data from client (reactjs)
    return jsonify(data='test')
# jsonify returns http response as json
```

Try it and see what you get! I hope this helps and good luck! 
Be aware of CORS

fetch api

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch